# joint_tests doesn't recognize asin.sqrt transformation via make.tran()

Tags: r, transformation, anova, emmeans

I have the following dummy model

```
tran = make.tran("asin.sqrt", 100)

mod <- with(tran,
lm(linkfun(cty) ~ manufacturer +  drv * linkfun(hwy), data = mpg))
```

but, I cannot get the ANOVA table with

```
joint_tests(mod)
Error in ratios && true.con && misc$tran %in% c("log", "log2", "log10",  : 
  'length = 5' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

emmeans does recognize the transformation, as detailed in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html.

```
emmeans(mod, ~ manufacturer, type = "response")
manufacturer response    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 audi             15.0 0.258 214     14.4     15.5
 chevrolet        16.1 0.240 214     15.7     16.6
 dodge            16.2 0.216 214     15.8     16.6
 ford             16.6 0.223 214     16.2     17.1
 honda            17.4 0.390 214     16.7     18.2
 hyundai          16.1 0.289 214     15.5     16.7
 jeep             16.5 0.362 214     15.8     17.2
 land rover       15.2 0.480 214     14.2     16.1
 lincoln          15.7 0.634 214     14.4     16.9
 mercury          16.0 0.479 214     15.1     17.0
 nissan           16.8 0.289 214     16.2     17.3
 pontiac          14.8 0.423 214     14.0     15.7
 subaru           16.9 0.356 214     16.2     17.6
 toyota           16.9 0.206 214     16.5     17.3
 volkswagen       16.5 0.248 214     16.0     17.0

Results are averaged over the levels of: drv 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the asin(sqrt(mu/100)) scale
```

How can I get around this issue? Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug that has been [recently fixed](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/428) for future updates in **emmeans**.