# joint_tests omits covariate transformed with asin(sqrt()) via make.tran()

Tags: r, transformation, emmeans, ancova

Relating to [joint_tests doesn't recognize asin.sqrt transformation via make.tran()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76837389/joint-tests-doesnt-recognize-asin-sqrt-transformation-via-make-tran) I have `emmeans` 1.8.8

```
set.seed(83)
library(emmeans)
dummy <- expand.grid(
  covar  = runif(72, min = 0, max = 1),
  resp = runif(72, min = 0, max = 2),
  site = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g"),
  C = 1:4,
  R = c("i", "j", "k")
)

as.tran <- make.tran("asin.sqrt")


mod <- with(as.tran, lm(sqrt(resp) ~ site  +  C * R * linkfun(covar), data = dummy))
```

This `joint_tests` command did not give any row that involved the covar.
joint_tests(mod)

```
model term df1    df2 F.ratio p.value
 site         5 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C            1 373231   0.000  1.0000
 R            2 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C:R          2 373231   0.000  1.0000
```

Switching `resp` and `covar`, and the `joint_tests(mod2)` below gave the full ancova model

```
mod2 <- with(as.tran, lm( linkfun(covar) ~ site  +  C * R * sqrt(resp), data = dummy))
joint_tests(mod2)
 model term df1    df2 F.ratio p.value
 site         5 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C            1 373231   0.000  1.0000
 R            2 373231   0.000  1.0000
 resp         1 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C:R          2 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C:resp       1 373231   0.000  1.0000
 R:resp       2 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C:R:resp     2 373231   0.000  1.0000
```

With `asin`, `joint_tests` recognize on-the-fly transformation of the covariate outside of `make.tran()`

```
mod3 <- lm( sqrt(resp) ~ site  +  C * R * asin(covar), data = dummy)

joint_tests(mod3)
 model term df1    df2 F.ratio p.value
 site         5 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C            1 373231   0.000  1.0000
 R            2 373231   0.000  1.0000
 covar        1 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C:R          2 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C:covar      1 373231   0.000  1.0000
 R:covar      2 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C:R:covar    2 373231   0.000  1.0000
```

but not in `make.tran()`

```
a.tran = make.tran("asin")

mod4 <- with(a.tran, lm(sqrt(resp) ~ site  +  C * R * linkfun(covar), data = dummy))

joint_tests(mod4)

 model term df1    df2 F.ratio p.value
 site         5 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C            1 373231   0.000  1.0000
 R            2 373231   0.000  1.0000
 C:R          2 373231   0.000  1.0000
```

Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was explained in the related [GitHub issue page](https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/438), the problem is that by default, covariates are reduced to an interval of two values that differ by 2. That throws both ends outside the legal interval of [0,1] for this transformation, resulting in `NaN` values and the covariate terms being hidden because they have 0 d.f. You will see results if you do, for example,

```
joint_tests(mod4, cov.reduce = function(x) mean(x) + c(-1,1)/10)
```

... so that a much shorter interval is used that puts everything within bounds.